# String Interpolation Segment Error in Swift 3

Tags: ios, string, swift3, string-interpolation

I recently upgraded my project to Swift 3 and have been having some trouble with a string interpolation error.

My code:

```
let coordString = "\(locationCoordinate.latitude) \(locationCoordinate.longitude)".stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: ",")
```

The error says:

> Static member 'init(stringInterpolationSegment:)' cannot be used on instance of type 'String'

How can I solve the error?

Comment: Basically use `(NS)Numberformatter` to display the decimal separator of a number according to the current locale. Further `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` has been renamed in Swift 3.

Comment: I am new to swift could you please write that in code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method has been renamed in Swift 3:

```
let coordString = "\(locationCoordinate.latitude) \(locationCoordinate.longitude)".replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the decimal separator using `replacingOccurrences(of...` is not good programming habit.

You should use always `NumberFormatter` to be able to consider the current locale of the user.

This is an example. The decimal separator is displayed depending on the current locale. If you really want explicit a comma uncomment the `locale` line and set the locale identifier to your preferred one.

```
let latitude = 52.5
let longitude = 13.0
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
// formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "DE_de")

let coordString = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:latitude))! + " " + formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:longitude))!
```

Comment: can you please explain me why this is better practice

Comment: For some languages (locales), "." should be used in decimal format (e.g. US English), but in others, "," should be used (e.g. many European languages). So just replacing "." with "," isn't probably a good idea because it doesn't take into account localization. It's better to let the formatter decide (based on the locale you set) whether to use "." or "," ...I think that's what @vadian is getting at.